# Error: IntelliSense: identifier "strlen" is undefined in C

Tags: c

I get this error twice, and I don't know why as I have stdlib.h included at the beginning
So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or forgetting to add?
Can anyone see why it might be showing up?
Error: IntelliSense: identifier "strlen" is undefined   in C

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

FILE*fp; 

char *symbols = "#~!$%^&*()+=<>?/@"; //Random Symbol is generated form this list

int main(void) {

char password[4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 1];
int i, j=0, len=sizeof(password)-1;
int menuNum = 0;
int passwordCheck[15+1];



fp = fopen("passwords.txt", "a+"); 
//Opens the text file to save the Passwords

srand(time(NULL));
printf("       Main Menu\n");
printf("********************************\n");
printf("\nEnter 1 to Generate a New Password: ");
printf("\n\n");
printf("Enter 2 to Check Old Passwords: ");
printf("\n\n");
printf("Enter 3 to Exit. ");
printf("\n\n");
scanf("%d", &menuNum); // reads number

if (menuNum == 1)
{
    printf("********************************\n");
    printf("\nYour New Password is: \n\n");

//Each Password will Have 12 Characters(4 Uppercase letters, 4 Lowercase letters, 2 Numbers & 2 Symbols)

for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    password[j++] = 'a' + rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1); //Generates 4 random Lowercase characters 

for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    password[j++] = 'A' + rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1); //Generates 4 random Uppercase characters

for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    password[j++] = '0' + rand() % ('0' - '9' + 1); //Generates 2 random numbers

for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    password[j++] = symbols[rand() % strlen(symbols)]; //Generates 2 random symbols

password[j] = '\0';
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(password)-1; ++i)
    {
    char c = password[i];
    j = rand() % len;
    password[i] = password[j];
    password[j] = c;
    }

printf("%s\n\n", password);
printf("********************************\n");
fprintf(fp, "\n%s", password); //Outputs the Generated Passoword to the text file
fclose(fp); //Closes the text file
system("pause");
}
else if (menuNum == 2)
{           
    printf("\nEnter your password for checking: ");
    scanf("%s", passwordCheck);  // reads password
    if (strlen(passwordCheck) > 15) // Checks length of Password
    {
        printf("'%s' is too long. Needs to be less then 15 Characters\n", passwordCheck);
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (strlen(passwordCheck) < 9) //Checks length of Password
    {
        printf("'%s' is too short. Needs to be more then 9 Characters\n", passwordCheck);
        system("pause");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `#include <string.h>` please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#include <string.h>
```

When you want to know what includes are needed for a function, read its man page.

Comment: I have used <string> instead of <string.h>. After writing as u said, the problem the problem solved. Can you tell me the difference between them? I know the .h stands for header file. But not more then that.

Comment: `<string>` would be for C++, not C. C++ standard header files don't end with `.h`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include <string.h>` or strings.h at the top of the program

This imports the prototype for the strlen function